# Is there a way to permanently attach the console window to the main XCode window?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, environment

Using XCode 3. I know there's an option preferences > debugging > On Start: show console. This automatically brings up a *separate* console window. Is there anyway to attach the console window so, say, it appears below code C code I'm currently working on?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to All-In-One mode of Xcode from it's preferences (it's possible, when all project windows are closed). After that you will have normal/debug mode switch and in debug mode will be able to see watch & console sections at the bottom.

Comment: You beauty! Wasn't aware all projects had to be closed. Thank you!